# How good enough it is to build a REST Api based server in C++?

Tags: c++11

I am looking from a security perspective and are there any frameworks available to build and use JSON?

I am interested because of the performance which C++ can offer. Currently, Python and Node.js are also available option for me. How can I decide which language+framework should I use ?

Appreciate your support.

Thanks !

PS. - Currently, I am using Java Spring to implement restful apis.

Comment: its impossible to suggest a framework if you are not sure what perforamance you are expecting from the rest server

Comment: @Pradheep : I am not expecting performance benchmark based on frameworks. I want to know comparison with python + django, java+spring and c+++anyframework.
Any whether i shoud use c++ for web server development or not !

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of them out there. The absolute simplest one I found, and use, is this. https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server .

There are clearly more sophisticated ones out there, just "ask the google". I don't know of any exhaustive comparisons between these frameworks and the ones you specified. However, you could write your own simple benchmarks around the domain you're most interested in. That's what really matters, right?

For json libs there's rapidjson and spirit json. Don't waste your time with boost::property_tree, it's not fully fleshed out wrt JSON.

As for speed. It's compiled so.... its a good possibility that a C++ framework will outperform one based on an interpreted language. So lets say it's faster, you have a heck of a learning curve to climb (assuming you don't know C++ already) but in the end, in my humble opinion it's worth it. I've done these before in Python and Ruby. I really enjoy having the compiler check types. My code is more robust, it does what I tell it to do, and I'm not forced to use exceptions.

Tip: get a code completion plugin like YouCompleteMe